# Detect iFrame embedding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey

I have an application that has a certain page -- let's call it Page A. Page A is sometimes a top-level page, but also sometimes is embedded as an iframe within page B. All pages come from the same server and there are no cross-domain issues.

I have a greasemonkey script that runs on page A. How can the greasemonkey script detect whether page A is within the iframe context or not?

Comment: Would you just look for at the parent for frames and see if they exist ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Looking at frame length breaks down generally if page A itself has frames (I know this might not be the case for this specific instance). The more reliable and meaningful test would be:

```
if (window!=window.top) { /* I'm in a frame! */ }
```

Comment: Can you explain? Is this because a.parent can equal a?

Comment: yes, exactly so - .top and .parent can point to the same object as .self (and in fact it would possibly be clearer to test window.self != window.top)

Comment: This didn't work for me inside a Firefox extension, but I found a different solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069#7769187

Comment: I confirm, for covering also IE8 you have to use window.parent.frames.length

Answer (score 12):

The predicate

```
(window.parent.frames.length > 0)
```

will tell you just what you want.

Comment: Just don't forget to do it after ;0)

Comment: This approach gives you false positive if you nest another iframe on the page you run this check on.

Comment: this is not that simple. if your page contains iframes, than window.parent == window so it would give false positive.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (top === self) { not in a frame } else { in a frame }
```

From [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th)

Answer (score 4):

As stated above the accepted solution doesn't work in IE8.  Additionally, checking `window.parent.frames.length` can cause a cross-domain exception.

Instead I was able to achieve this with `var isInIFrame = top.location != self.location` - it works in IE8 and it doesn't cause a cross-domain violation as long as you don't attempt to read the contents of `top.location`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.frameElement` and check if it is not null and if its nodeName is "IFRAME".

Comment: This element is not available in Safari or Opera. Given the number of people surfing on iPads these days, this probably isn't a suitable solution.