# how to judge a page is in a iframe use javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, this

i use javascript to judge a page is in a iframe:

```
if (this != top) {
    alert("true");
}
```

[image]

but i get "true" all the time,even if not in a iframe(as up picture),who can help me?

Comment: [An old question of possible interest.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997)

Comment: Or possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925039/detect-iframe-embedding-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
if (self != top) {
    alert("true");
}
```