# Can I avoid double tracing if parent and iframe runs the same Google Analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

How can i use event tracking feature in a iframe if the parent document uses the same Google Analytics ID but i don't want to double the pageview number?
Can I disable the default page tracking or switch to "manual tracking"?

The story in brief: The parent document displays the comments in a iframe and i want to track some clicks inside the comment frame. I don't want to use different GA account to parent and child and also I don't want to merge the iframe into the parent document. I hope you can help me, I'll give you a FREE virtual BEER if you want some.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe documents [can detect that they are being iframed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925039/detect-iframe-embedding-in-javascript).

You can revert the logic and fire the GA tracking code only when outside of a frame:

```
if (window.self === window.top) { /* I'm NOT in a frame! */
// GA tracking code 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']) ;
}
```

Does this answer your question  ?