# Is there any clever way for Javascript to know its being executed in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need the script to dynamically change how it functions if the page is embedded via an iFrame.

The script will be called in the iFrame source from a `<script..` tag and wont be inline javascript.

Thank You in Advance!

**Update:**  David provided this answer which works in Firefox and Chrome but doesn't work in IE8, any help with this is appreciated : )

```
if (window !== top) {
  alert('im in an frame');
}
```

**Update2:** Apparently this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th), the right answer is:

```
if (top === self) { alert('parent'); } else { alert('iframe'); }
```

Credit goes to [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th/326076#326076)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (top === self) { alert('parent'); } else { alert('iframe'); }
```

Works fine! Credit goes to [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th/326076#326076)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (window != top) {
  // In a frame of some kind
}
```

Comment: I think StackOverflow implements this method. `<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"/>`

Comment: hmm, works great in chrome and firefox, doesn't seem to work in IE8, thanks though!

Comment: `if (window !== top) {alert(window);}` returns `[object]` from the page and `[object Window]` from the iFrame in IE (not working correctly), in firefox only the second is returned (working correctly) and in chrome `[object DOMWindow]` is returned (also working correctly). I hope this helps. (btw the window.parent suggestion fails to work in both firefox and chrome)

Comment: Actually there is a super easy answer to this.. you could always test  `window.location.hostname` against the expected address of your domain to see if the page is being embedded. This seems a bit fragile though. And could introduce unwanted behavior in the future with domain name change.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not return true for the equivalence operator (===) for two references to the same window object- even in a top level window, if(window===top) returns false.

But the simpler equality operator if(window==top) returns true in all the browsers if the object is the top window, and false if it is an iframe contained in a window.

Comment: Actually it seems to return true in both cases, I just tested it.  Thanks tho!