# Check if parent window is iframe or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I tell from a page within an iframe, if the parent itself is also within an iframe?

***Explanation:***

My home page `home.html` contains an iframe

```
<iframe src="sample.html"></iframe>
```

I need to detect if `home.html` (ie: parent of `sample.html`) is within an iframe.

Code in `sample.html`:

```
if(self==window)
{
    alert('home.html is not in iframe');
}
else
{
    alert('home.html is in iframe');
}
```

My question is not a duplicate. It's a different case.

Comment: It's a bit unclear... Do you have an iframe in a page in an iframe? Do you want to check if a page is in an iframe, or if the page containing the iframe is in an iframe?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th

Comment: What is the differents then? :s

Comment: once home.html is an iframe then i need to detect home.html is an iframe from sample.html.

Comment: none of the answer works

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is true if a window is not a frame/iframe:

```
if(self==top)
```

If you like to see if the parent window of the given window is a frame, use:

```
if(parent==top)
```

It's a simple comparision of `top` (the most top window of the window hierarchy) and another window object (`self` or `parent`).

Comment: testing top isn't so great if you expect that your frame might live in a frame off-domain. E.g. your site is hosted in someone elses via a frame / iframe reference (as sometimes happens with blog templates sites, etc). Since "top" might be in a different domain, testing parent == top can throw a cross domain error. Try putting a marker in the container frame and test for that (e.g. if (parent.myVar)

Comment: @frumbert, if 'top' might throw a cross-domain error, wouldn't 'parent' also?

Comment: @frumbert: testing a window will not throw an error(parent.myVar is not a test for a window, it's a test for a property of a window, what is slightly different)

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Yep of course. So to avoid cross domain errors you have to catch the possible exception. The answer on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672721/get-highest-frame-that-still-is-on-domain : could be extended to test for the iframe (OP) and bail out if it hit a cross domain error, while still catching exceptions.

Comment: Nope, of course not. show 1 example where accessing a `window`-object results in an cross-domain-error(that's all we talk about here, `window`-objects, nothing more). The linked question has nothing to do with the question here.

Comment: There may also be an issue with detecting iFrame-ness before the iFrame has been added to its parent, though I'm by no means certain of this and it may be an edge case or due to the fact I'm working in Safari here.

Answer (score 36):

Check if `window.frameElement` is not null and see if its nodeName property is "IFRAME":

```
var isInIframe = window.frameElement && window.frameElement.nodeName == "IFRAME";
```

Comment: This answer is great because it contains a simple and straight-forward way to access the `iframe` element which contains the current page (when it's loaded inside such).

Comment: I agree with @Oliver. This way is so much simpler than the other two answers above and any other strategy I've seen for dealing with this issue. This should be the accepted answer...

Comment: This fails for cross-origin iframes. 

    Returns the element (such as <iframe> or <object>) in which the window is embedded, or null if the element is either top-level or is embedded into a document with a different script origin; that is, in cross-origin situations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Answer (score 24):

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location);
if(isInIFrame==true){
    // iframe
}
else {
    // no iframe
}
```

Comment: or just `var isInIFrame = window.location !== window.parent.location;` would work as well.

Comment: There's an edge case in which this won't work: if you've loaded the same page into the iframe that contains the iframe.

Comment: also, cross-domain or similar protection will cause a script error when accessing window.parent propery

Comment: @oriadam if it throws an error you can assume it's in an iframe