# jQuery: Check if content is sitting inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm loading a page through an iframe. If the content is sitting inside an iframe I need to add a loading spinner and if not, then no need for the spinner.

Problem: 
How can I use jQuery to check from **within** the content in the iframe if it's currently sitting in an iframe or not?

(i.e. it's simple to add jQuery to the page which loads the iframe itself, but I need the jQuery code to be in the file that's loaded **inside** the iframe).

Comment: I think you can check if `window.parent != window`

Comment: This post seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594492/to-check-parent-window-is-iframe-or-not.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

How about

```
if ( self !== top ) {
// you're in an iframe
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using your proposed solution and `if( window.self !== window.top ) {/*in an iframe*/}` ?

Comment: As far as I know, both should give you the same result. So no.

Comment: it works. but keep in mine, if u're using safari it will not work as planned.