# how can I make a page opening only into the iframe and not if it's called directly?

Tags: php, iframe

The content generate by `list.php` should be only opened into an iframe tag, on the `index.php`. But when it's called directly, it should not be possible to open it.
How can I obtain this?

In fact I already adopete this method:

```
<iframe title="frame" class="iframe" src="http://www.example.com/list.php?type=a&amp;013acd2b6c1368f">[Your browser doesn%27;t support iframes]</iframe>
```

which works fine, thus if the file is called without the arguments ,it redirects to the index.

**BUT** if you call it directly in this way `http://www.example.com/list.php?type=a&amp;013acd2b6c1368f` the content appears at full page. While I want that, being outside the tag  , it redirects to `Index.php`

Is there any way please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to any one.

After have written this message, I finally found the answer here and with small adaption it worked out perfectly.
I didn't find this post before.

[Answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594492/to-check-parent-window-is-iframe-or-not)