# Change CSS if page is embedded into iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have seen questions here about changing the CSS of iframe content from a parent site/page. However, i want the child page to detect if it is in an iframe and then change the CSS.

Thus this should be in the embedded page:

```
iframe body{color: red;}
```

This doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work or do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if parent window is iframe or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594492/check-if-parent-window-is-iframe-or-not)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava |Thanks. That is what I used in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You should apply CSS to the `iframe` tag.
Like:

```
iframe {
  color: red;
}
```

This will work as expected.