# is it possible to track ip or traffic from 3rd party using iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

i have a website and i'm wondering if it is possible to track with some type of coding to see if someone is placing my website into an iframe and displaying it on their site? i have checked my log in the cpanel and nothing is there but when i go to this other website clearly they are iframing my site. I am aware of JavaScript to make it pop out of the iframe but for my site i cant use this. thanks again.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-th

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, by add some js code into your page like this:

```
if(self != top){
   //js code to track it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the article on Wikipedia about [Framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller). You'll learn how you can detect that your site has been embedded in an iframe but also that there are solutions to counter it: [Framekiller Killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller#Framekiller_Killers)