# Redirect if site is not shown in a frame

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a page i only want to be visible if it is shown in a iframe.

Is this possible in PHP, htaccess or something? how?

I would prefer a solution in PHP

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frames are client side only so you can't check it through PHP or .htaccess. You can check it in Javascript. See this thread:

[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

**EDIT**
Here's an example that would redirect for you. It's straight Javascript but if you were doing this with jQuery you could write the same function into `document.ready`

```
<script>
function check_frame() {
     if( top === self ) { // not in a frame
          location.href = "/link/to/some/url"; // either the frameset or an error.
     }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="check_frame()">
... normal code for your page here ...
</body>
```

Note that the page can still be a PHP page, it would just need to output that bit of Javascript.

Comment: Ok, so Im not into Javascript at all, can you give me an example?

Comment: Why the need for document.ready? It's just plain JS, so will work with, or without jQuery.

Comment: @Gerben - I just included that if he's already using jQuery it would make more sense to include that in document.ready instead of using onLoad

Comment: Missed that. There is however no need to wait for onload. You can just run the code directly, and avoid the delay.