# As a page, can I tell if I've been loaded into an iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a page into an iframe. Both pages are on the same domain. I want the page being loaded to do specific js functionality only if it has been loaded into an iframe. Is this possible?

Bonus: can it be done in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a job for the Circa 1997 `self==top` trick

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

or just:

```
var isEmbed = window != window.parent;
```

Answer (score 9):

Probably the simplest method:

```
if ( self !== top ) {
    // you're in an iframe
}
```

So, you check if the current window is the topmost window...

Answer (score -2):

You could use iframe's onload event:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
alert("Iframe is loaded");
}
</script>
</head>

<iframe onload="load()" src="/page.html">
</iframe>    
</html>
```

Comment: unclear answer ? where should he put the code ? btw your code isn formatted in anyway.