# Force domain with frame

Tags: html, redirect, seo, dns, frames

I've registered *domain.com* at [Loopia](https://www.loopia.com/) and use their "redirect", which actually opens a website in a frame - in this case *mysite.com/domain*. However, if I visit *mysite.com/domain* I want to get redirected to *domain.com*.

Is this possible, and how would it affect search engines?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your answer is here, at least partially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t But I have no idea how this will affect your SEO.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about that method, but it feels like it wont affect the search engines. Right now *mysite.com/domain* unfortunately gets indexed instead of *domain.com*

Comment: Ehm, yes, because the content is in there instead of in `domain.com`. But you can go to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and tell them that `domain.com` is your site and that they shouldn't spider `mysite/domain`. Not sure about other search engines.

Comment: Ah okay, I've never worked with frames before as I'm normally against them, so thanks for the information. I'll see if I could find an alternative solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can **park your domain** instead of **redirect** it or open your website in a iframe.
When you park your domain, actually your new domain contains all data(s) in previous domain and I think this is a better method.

Furthermore, you don't loose any page rank or SEO ranks.

Comment: Hm, that sounded interesting - does the content get "transfered" to the domain if I park it?

Comment: According to themselves, their own "red screen" will be displayed when a domain is parked. I'll test and return - if it against all expectations works, then you'll have my thanks.

Comment: OK, who is "themselves"? If this is a free hosting site, I might be able to find you another that does allow your own domain to be parked. If it's not free, but it still doesn't allow parking, well, what can I say.

Comment: "Themselves" would mean the host, Loopia, as mentioned, and no it's not free. Apparently your method didn't work, but thank you anyway. :-)

Comment: @Ivarska But I was talking about the site you call `mysite.com/domain`, where your content is hosted. You mean it isn't them that give you troubles with the parking, but Loopia? That would be strange. (By the way, you said my method, but did you mean Afshin's method?)

Comment: Oh, I messed up the names, haha. But yeah, you got it all right. I got tired of the problem, though, and bought a web server with a dedicated IP instead. It feels like it's a more stable solution.