# How can I tell if my jQuery code is being run inside an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am having lots of issues on a website because my jQuery is causing errors due to the fact that it is being rendered inside of an iFrame. Is there any way I can tell my jQuery not to load when it is inside of an iFrame?

Comment: Seems like dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @Greg answer

`if (top === self) { not in a frame } else { in a frame }`

top and self are both window objects (along with parent), so you're seeing if your window is the top window.

[Greg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
window.opener != null
```

Answer (score 1):

As Greg said in the link in the comment on the question, you can use 'if(top===self){ outside iframe code here } else { inside iframe code here}' to do this.