# How to add body class in Wordpress if the page is being viewed in an iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, wordpress

From the post [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) I understand you can detect whether or not your page is being viewed through a frame or not.

Using a WordPress site.  I'd like to append a body class tag to my site dependent on it's view.  I'm doing this so I can tweak the styling.  I understand this can't be done via PHP and you need to use JavaScript.

Can somebody walk me through an example of how I can add my body class with this?

```
if (top === self) { not iframe -do nothing } else { in a frame - add body class }
```

Thanks in advance for the hand holding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery by adding this snippet to your document `head`. This will add to the body class attribute if the page with javascript code is being embedded through an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
  if(isInIFrame) {
    $('body').addClass('iframe');
  }
});
</script>
```

You can view some more source code for this answer [on Github](https://github.com/jordanandree/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/12332674)

Comment: Worked Awesome!  Thanks so much Jordan.