# How do I prevent visitors from opening a page outside iframe

Tags: php

i need to prevent visitors from opening a page outside iframe

for example

when write on browser :

```
www.sss.com/index.php
```

will be open

but when write

```
www.sss.com/add_news.php
```

i need to redirect to home page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an iframe makes a GET request there isn't really any way to distinguish a GET request coming from the browser itself and one coming from an iframe embedded in a page.  In both cases the browser makes the same GET request.  You could probably write some JavaScript code in your "iframe" page that detects whether or not it is loaded in the top window and redirects if it isn't.

From the accepted answer on [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

using the window properties `top` and `self`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top === self) {
        location = '/index.php';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: by javascript or what ??

Comment: Yes. You'd include this snippet of JavaScript inside the page being loaded into the iframe.

Comment: @KAMMAL `top` is the top most window in the current tab.  `self` is the current frame.  If `top` is equal to `self` then the page is loaded in the top most window and you need to redirect to the parent page.  If it is loaded in an iframe, then `top` will not be equal to `self` and it won't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to generate some token eg. "982h2jruhndjf92", store it on server or in cookie then add it as GET param to the in-frame script.

```
<iframe src="www.sss.com/add_news.php?token=982h2jruhndjf92" />
```

if url provides same token you show the right view, otherwise redirect user using header() function.

Comment: All that requires, though, is that the user inspect the page and enter the url with the token attached.

Comment: but i open other page on this frame by using target

Comment: i think there is no way to prevent such a situation. Everything that is on the client side can be inspected and manipulated - DOM and scripts. Probably the simpliest way is to check top===self, but inspecting and copying iframe src attribute then pasting it to browser adres bar is pretty trivial way to do. I think the strongest security would give storing some flag (eq. for 10 seconds) in session while requesting top page, then when client requests frame page and there is flag in session stored you can send the response, redirect otherwise. All the logic should be on server to be safe

Answer (score -1):

using just php you could do it with the header

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: www.sss.com/index.php' ) ;

?>
```

Comment: He only wants the redirect when the page isn't being loaded in a iframe.  This will redirect it every time.