# Security check to avoid direct visitor on a page

Tags: security

I have a page that I want to be loaded only from an iFrame.

I use the solution on this link to do it.
[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

but it doesn't work in IE so I use conditional comments like this

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://mysite.com/nodirectvisit.html";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Together they are now working in IE, Chrome, FF, and Opera.

I just want to ask if there are still other ways to visit my page directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a user disables javascript, then your code will not run. Maybe use Sessions to track from where users are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with javascript disabled or NoScript would be able to open the page directly.  The javascript should prevent the majority of users.

You can check the referrer of the iframe page to make sure it's the page that contains the iframe. The referrer isn't the most reliable field, but if you're more worried about people visiting the page not in an iframe than people not being able to see it at all, that might be the way to go.