# Can I detect that content is loaded in an iframe or the main window using server side in c# ?

Tags: c#, iframe

I'm letting people to use my website content in an iframe in their website, when they use iframe I add a QueryString to the end of the address that is the id of the website showing my website's content and instead of loading my own logo I will load the customized user logo like this:

http://www.amsofts.com?s=1

the problem is that, I'm afraid that this query gets indexed by search engines and when a user clicks on search results (that has s=index ad the end ) and in my own website another logo would be shown. I want that if the content is being loaded in main window and not an iframe, even if there is this QueryString, I show my own website logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this server-side. There is nothing in the request to identify that a request was made from an iframe. You could potentially [detect this using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326076/1043198) and replace the logo client-side, however.

Comment: well do you have any other suggestion on choosing witch logo to show?

Comment: Why not use Javascript as per my link? You can default to using your own logo, using Javascript to detect the query string value and apply it if you're in an iframe.