# How to redirect a google blog page....unless it is being contained in an iframe?

Tags: redirect, iframe, meta-tags, blogger, http-equiv

So I have a google blog page which I would like to redirect to my page which I have an iframe of my google blog page. When I put the following code in, it redirects to my page containing the iframe:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=//mysite.com"/>
```

However obviously, in the iframe it continuously redirects and just fills up the page with the iterating header.

I found many ways to test if a page is being loaded in a browser or an iframe (such as this solution: [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)) however they all use javascript or script tags which Blogger does not seem to support (it refuses to save changes). Is there a way to do this test just using HTML?

Answer (score 0):

No. But the web server can detect it via the existence of a referrer string. Here is one way to do it in an Apache .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Referer ^http remote

<FilesMatch "\.(html|xml)">
  order deny,allow
  deny from env=remote
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**References**

- [Testing for SSI Injection (OTG-INPVAL-009) - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SSI_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-009))