# How to identify a webpage is loaded inside an IFRAME or a FRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame

I am developing a "content script" of Chrome Extension. It has to activate some javascript functions if the page is loaded in a <FRAME> but no in an <IFRAME>.

I know that I can check window.frameElement by

`var inIFrame = (window.frameElement.tagName=='IFRAME')`

But it failed if the child frame is not in the same domain with the parent frame. It throws cross-domain security warning. How the child frame knows it is in IFRAME or FRAME without violating the security policy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Comment: @Niels, this is not duplication. My point is in what kind of frame, the IFRAME or FRAME.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't entirely clear. I'll type an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible to determine. The child document cannot cross its security boundaries, and if the domain is different and no other CORS permissions are in place its 'visible world' is limited to the scope of its own document, ie its own window. There is no way to look beyond that into the parent document's scope, and determine the type of the containing element. Doing so would expose the entire object and its attributes, including all potential exploits of that knowledge.