# Hide header if in iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, header

I need to hide the header of my wordpress-based website, in case the site is loaded in an iFrame.
Should I do it with javascript, in functions or in css? And how can I do it?
I found this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location);
   if(isInIFrame==true){
       alert("It's in an iFrame");
       document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none";
       }
   else {
       alert("It's NOT in an iFrame");
       }
   </script>
```

But I don't where to put it (and also I don't know if it could work).
I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I grabbed this code (and modified it for your use) from this post so go there and give Greg an upvote :) [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

```
function inIframe() {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch () {
        return true;
    }
}

if(inIframe){
    document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none"; //if you want javascript only
    $("#header").hide(); // if you want jquery
}
```

However this will only work if the header has the ID "header".

Comment: I managed to get it working But now I have, instead of header, an arbitrary 57px padding.

here is the output result 

    <body class="home.page.page-id-10.page-template.page-template-page-templatesfront-page-php.custom-background.mini-header.fixed-header" style="padding-top: 57px"; >

Comment: $("#header").hide().css('padding-top', 0); would remove the padding.