# if my site is in an iframe I don't want the header to show in any pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I was trying the solution found in: [Hide header if in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584610/hide-header-if-in-iframe)
and when the iframe is laoded it truly works, but if I click in any link on my website the header appears, I don't want the header to be shown in ANY pages if it is in a iframe.

for now my code is

```
function no_header_iframe(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}

if(inIframe()){
    $('nav').addClass('hidden').hide();
}
</script>
<?php } 
add_action('wp_footer', 'no_header_iframe');
```

since my site is in wordpress.

How can I hide the header in all the pages? (if the site is loaded in an iframe, of course)

Comment: how about loading the same js code in each page where you would like this header hiding effect to be in place?   Edit: if you have a master page, you can place the code in your master page such that it is loaded on all pages that uses this master page

Comment: @Ji_in_coding I putted it in the footer of all my pages, when I add the action to the wp_footer it adds it in the footer.php archive wich is loaded in every page :/

Comment: Try to comment out your iframe detection, simply turn off header iregardless of iframe or browser. Visit a couple pages in your browser to make sure it is working. Then test in iframe again. Maybe that can help you narrow down root of cause.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Thanks! Just discovered that jquery wasn't loading in other pages and that's why the code didn't worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ji_in_coding said, you'll need to include (and run) that javascript code on each pages.

If you have a index.php page that uses include for all your website content, you can include the code there.
if not, you'll need to include it on every page.