# Override a page's CSS when put in an iframe

Tags: php, css, iframe, curl, file-get-contents

Is it possible to take a web page that lets say has CSS that makes the header `position:fixed`, then use php and use either `cURL` or `file_get_contents`, and apply my own CSS file to change that header to `position:absolut`?

Comment: I would be putting the page then inside an iframe.

Comment: Sure you can do that but remember that you also have to rewrite every relative path used in the html. Every src, href and posibly javascript and css attributes have to potentialy be rewritten, not an easy task

Comment: All PHP does is put an HTML file together and send it to the client. So eg file_get_contents gets the HTML from another page and puts it in yours, then sends it to the client. CSS is clientside which means you can override any style

Comment: You can't over-ride styles in an iFrame, since an iFrame doesn't actually have any styles...it's a page unto itself with it's own style associations.

Comment: Here's your answer: It can be done if a) the content of the iFrame is coming from the same domain as the parent page and b) you use JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe?rq=1

Comment: @DA. Hm i missed the iFrame part

Comment: @DA. I was trying to take an eternal site, use file_get_contents and display that page on my host. Then use a CSS page and then take the page with file_get_contents and put it on another page inside an iframe.

Comment: @Jared so you are essentially screen-scraping? If so, the iFrame is moot, as it's now your file on your server and you can do with it as you see fit (at least technically speaking...there may be legal issues, but that's another story...). In that case, you simply want to inject your over-ride CSS links into the file you are inserting into the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some JavaScript to identify whether or not your page is in an iframe
(Look here for more information: [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)).

Then, you could simply insert inline CSS based on this, make the page import different CSS files, etc.