# Most effective way of determining whether called page is being loaded inside iframe or directly from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I want to check whether the loaded page is loaded directly from browser or called inside any frame including Facebook application as canvas page.

This is really important for me. I found out this question [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) but some people said that it doesn't work at some browsers ?

I can also use jquery if that provides better solution or this solution is the best ?

Thank you very much for the answers

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not want to use !== since in IE, self and top refer to two different proxy objects, and you will get a false positive. Use != instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-check-window-iframe/

```
function isIframe() {
var isInIframe = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
alert(isInIframe);
}
```

Comment: so you think that this is better approach and would work at more browsers ?