# Determine if url of page is the parent or inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

Is there a way to determine if a page inside an iframe can be distinguished from that same child page being accessed directly from the browser?  I need to do a redirect to a page if that page isnt inside an iframe.  This iframe is not cross domain so I do have access to it.  I would like to specifically do this on the server side but if I cant I can do it client.

Comment: is this what you look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t ?

Comment: That is the answer, mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) property of iframe to get its `location` object. Then check `location.href` property:

```
var iframeUrl = iframe.contentWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: Can I do a comparison with that and the current URL of the page? `if(iframe.contentWindow.location.href == location.href) //redirect`