# How to show mobile screen design on large screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am having an issue while switching a design between devices. I know that css3 `@media` queries are use to handle on the bases of device width, orientation etc.

As far as concern with the device size css media queries are working perfectly fine when am on large screen size or on mobile screen size.

e.g

This is the design for mobile screen size.

[image]

and this is the design for large screen 
[image]

the media queries are working fine to switch the design. But i want to show the mobile screen design on desktop screen when the parent div size is small e.g equals to mobile screen size?

In the below situation i need to shown the mobile screen design on desktop screen size.
[image]

I googled it but didn't find any luck. I also try with different options of media queries. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Sorry I forget to mention that am using [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework for responsive design.

Comment: You can use emulator of google chrome or resize window size (maybe) @media less than would work when resizing windows

Comment: are you using device-width or screen-width?

Comment: Similar to Darshan's answer, in Firefox you can get responsive design mode from the developer tools. Press F12, and on the top right part there is a button called "Responsive Design Mode"

Comment: How about  [this](http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/)?

Comment: the responsive design working perfectly fine. I need to show the mobile screen design on large screen. Is there any way to show the small screen size design on the bases of parent div width?

Comment: there is no Issue of switching design between mobile screen and desktop screen size. I want to show the small screen size on large screen size? Do you guys get my point?

Comment: Use iframe with small size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media queries target the screen. Let's suppose you have the following structure:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you check the `width` with media query, you are essentially checking the screen `width`. However, if you check the `width`:

```
function isLarge(element, limit) {
    return element.width() >= limit;
}
```

and you add a class based on the size:

```
function addSizeClass(element, limit) {
    element.addClass(isLarge(element, limit) ? "large" : "small");
}
```

and you call the `function` for the parent of your element:

```
addSizeClass($("#bar").parent(), 700);
```

then, you can design `.large` and `.small`, like this:

```
.large div {
    /*your rules*/
}

.small div {
    /*your rules*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not link your media queries to the div size.

The usual way to handle this is to link them to screen-width, and set the div width to some percentage of the screen width.

Now, you only need to do some math ..

The basic issue here is that you should do a variable/responsive design for all your page, not only the list

Comment: how about using iframe ( as mention by @Petroff in comment )? is this a good way ?

Comment: Using an iframe is a good way if it doesn't create problems in the way you handle your page. But quite probably it will give you problems somewhere. Anyway, Petroff answer is more related to doing it in a development scenario that in production

Comment: you are right i try using iframe and it raise issue with angular scope. I think i have to go with your solution.

Comment: YAY! i fix the issue. The only solution is by making calculation. If you dont want to got into maths then creating a parent class and copy the small screen css with in it. So that on large screen when you mention the parent class it will react as a mobile design.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used foundation framework. But in media query you can give condition of screen max width :

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

// write your code here of css for mobile device

}

Now , suppose if u want make differentiate with mobile device or large device
you can use **width** property for both of them in css.

So that you can make margin between

> name : Collette Simko
>
> Events by Collete

Answer (score -1):

You can always use an iframe to display the page on your development version, instead of altering your browser settings. Might make it easier for universal testing as well.

---

**JavaScript**

```
function iframe( ) {
    try { return window.self !== window.top; }
    catch( e ) { return true; }
}

if ( !iframe( ) ) {
    theParent = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ];
    theIframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
    theIframe.className = "smallScreen";
    theIframe.src = "http://example.com/"; // Replace the address with your site address
    theParent.insertBefore( theIframe, theParent.firstChild );
}
```

---

**CSS**

```
iframe.smallScreen {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 800px;
    width: 500px;
    right: 500px;
    top: 50px
}
```

---

We use this technique at work when doing Facebook applications, works very well for testing and no need to resize your window all the time – can see both sizes simultaneously and everything works on both ends.

If you are using jQuery, you might as well do something like the following (use the CSS code above in conjunction with this).

---

**JavaScript** *(jQuery implementation)*

```
function iframe( ) {
    try { return window.self !== window.top; }
    catch( e ) { return true; }
}

if ( !iframe( ) )
    $( "body" ).prepend( '<iframe class="smallScreen" src="http://example.com/" />' ); // Replace the address with your site address
```

---

Frame detection picked from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326076/3264799).

Not exactly bulletproof, depends which libraries you use, but certainly worth a shot and works for the most part.

Comment: The question is not about testing a responsive design (did you know most browsers offer developer tools for that?), but about switching the design depending on the size of a surrounding div.