# How To hide button when pages open in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to `display: none` , the `save` button , when my html page opens in iframe.

How can I do it ?

This link might help me , but I did not understand this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t).

**iframe code**

```
<HTML>  
 <BODY>
   <iframe id="myiFrame" src="file:///C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/test.html"> </iframe>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**test.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <HTML>
   <BODY>
         <button id="hideInIframe" >save</button>
         <button id="getData" >get</button>
   </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
// you're in an iframe
}
```

Finally:

```
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
  $("#hideInIframe").css('display','none');
}
```

This way, each time test.html is in an iframe (of yours, or of anyone else), the save button is hide.

Answer (score 0):

In your *test.html* add this script and do one change add a name attribute to the iframe object:

```
<iframe id="myiFrame" id="myiFrame" src="file:///C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/test.html"> </iframe>
```

Then add this script.

```
<script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      if(window.name === 'myiFrame'){
        document.querySelector('#hideInIframe').style.display = 'none';
      }
   });
</script>
```