# check if xpages app resides in iframe in IBM Connections

Tags: javascript, iframe, xpages, ibm-connections, ssjs

I want to make available an xpages app available via ibm connections and since they both share the same titlebar header I want to hide the one in the xpages app when it resides in an iframe.

I have read that all JavaScript functions are blocked when embedded in the Connections IFrame widget so something simple like:

```
if (window.frameElement) {
  //window resides in an iframe...
  $( "#titlebar").hide();
}
```

does not work.

Is there another to check if my xpages application resides in an iframe? (ssjs?)

Comment: have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Answer (score 0):

In my widget javascript in Connections I post a postMessage back.
In my XPages I have a bit code to perform some script to do after receiving the postMessage.
This should be available in your browser, parent.postMessage and do something