# How to determine if JS code executes in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I determine whether a script executes in iframe or not? The solution should work in Android, iOS, Windows Mobile browsers.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: is it what you're looking for ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: this is answer for 7 years ago