# Redirecting users from Iframes & specific websites to a given webpage

Tags: javascript

Yesterday some scammers have used my website signup form through their fake website redirect to get people to sign up and steal their passwords.
[what actually happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLbfS.png)

I believe, when users have signed up through their fake website using my form, they would just catch the passwords mid-process. They would spam my website at similar topic websites for users to sign up. There was a jump in sign-ups, and it caused my suspicious so I noticed this. Is there any way to block users from iframes registering? Or sending people from that link to a web page notifying them that they were trying to be scammed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Comment: You can set headers on your page to control of it can be displayed within iframes or not. May help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: I don't really know how to implement that code since I'm not a developer myself... Sorry about this.