# Determine If Loaded From Iframe Server Side No Client

Tags: html, css, iframe, server-side

Is there a way from the server side to determine if the page being loaded is within an iframe, our a stand alone page?  Is there a head or something that tells you it's within an iframe without the client telling you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Comment: Why not just check for the presence of a second `<head>` tag?

Comment: @MikeFlynn What do you mean from the server side? You send the HTML to the client. The server doesn't know or care where the data is going. Can you post a [mcve] so we can duplicate your issue?

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to target an iframe's content from the server? Why do you not want to do this client-side? Why can you not simply run a conditional that checks that the output location is an `<iframe>` tag before outputting your page server-side? I'm afraid I'm rather confused as to what you're actually asking. Can you please update your question to provide some more clarity?

Comment: Wow. You ask a question that multiple people think is vague, then tell people trying to extract more information out of you **in order to help you** to simply not bother. Please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then people won't **have** to ask for clarification.

Comment: **All commenters:** please review the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy. Comments are not for extended discussion, nor are they for lecturing each other.

Comment: Thank you for being thorough on my question duskwuff.  These other guys are posting links to policies because they can't understand  a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

If your page is being loaded in an iframe, the URL of the parent frame will be in the `Referer` header (unless referrer policies prevent it from being sent). However, the same thing will happen if your page is being loaded as the result of the user clicking a link on the source page -- there's no way to tell the two apart from the server side.