# Unable to scrape specific URL

Tags: php, json, xpath, scrape, m3u8

I have a Kodi plugin and use PHP to scrape a lot of different sources for content. I recently stumbled across:

```
http://m.ddizi1.com/izle/60108/dolunay-10-bolum-hd.htm
```

I scrape through to the iframe and get:

```
http://trdizi.tv/player/oynat/2b152084a9c67ee35fdf5cab208157c7
```

Streaming this runs perfectly via the embedded link (on m.ddizi1.com), however if you run directly via browser, nothing comes up? I've tried to check for user-agents, referrer's, no luck.

Same story with this source too:

```
https://www.videoseyredin.net/diziler/yabanci/shooter-2-sezon-3-bolum-izle.html
```

I can scrape the .json playlist:

```
https://www.videoseyredin.net/playlist/179781.json
```

But then no love when trying to access the link directly in order to retrieve m3u8 and/or mp4 files...

Any suggestions? I've had no luck with both of these sources....

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you can share some of your code, it may help in fixing it.

Comment: Hi mate, it's more understanding how to access those links. What's preventing me from accessing it via a browser? I think theres a redirect? Could I manipulate headers, user agent etc?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though it's checking if it's being played in an iframe, if you create a page with

```
<body><iframe src="http://trdizi.tv/player/oynat/2b152084a9c67ee35fdf5cab208157c7"></iframe></body>
```

it will play.

This can be done by various methods, (from [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t))  one being...

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Update: The way I've managed to get it to work is...

1. Put the url which doesn't play
   (http://trdizi.tv/player/oynat/2b152084a9c67ee35fdf5cab208157c7)
   into the browser (Chrome) and this displays 'trdizi' Then right
   mouse click and Inspect.
2. When the html comes up - right mouse click the body tag and 'Edit as
       HTML'
3. Paste in the `<iframe src="http://trdizi.tv/player/oynat/2b152084a9c67ee35fdf5cab208157c7">
   </iframe>`
   (Can't remember how I get out of HTML Edit)

The page then displays the video.
This also shows you the html of the page loaded, so you maybe then able to see how it's blocking you.

Comment: Hmmm if I do: <html><body><iframe src="ht></iframe></body></html> it still doesn't launch...

Comment: Interesting - I've added to the answer how I've managed to display it, your right it isn't as simple a I'd hoped, but hopefully this may help.

Comment: Hmm it's probably impossible to scrape it then using xpath.