# Implementing Google Tag Manager in an Iframe

Tags: google-tag-manager

Tag manager code has been implemented within an iframe on a webpage. It has not been added to the webpage that contains the iframe.

Ive used tag manager to then implement a floodlight tag, and looking at the stats it seems to be double firing.

Do you know why this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a blocker to avoid send data when you load this on an iframe, you can use this variable (Custom Javascript)

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

And create a blocker when this var is true

Comment: thanks for your response, but I want to count the iframe. Its the iframe data i'm interested in, not the page the iframe is contained in.

Comment: I see, but GTM is on both ( Page and iframes)? because is a common reason to have double firing, this is caused because you're loading 2 times the GTM. So a option, in that case, is backward the condition. using true instead of false.