# Detecting if my page is being loaded in an iFrame in a Django view

Tags: django, iframe, django-views

How can I detect in a view function that the page is being loaded in an iFrame? I want to change the page slightly if that is the case. Is there any way to do this?

Note, Im not looking for click jacking protection. I want to make changes to my view if the page is being loaded in an iframe.

Comment: Do you have access to client code?

Comment: @dvnguyen Nope, I don't

Comment: No chance - the server just get an request to deliver the page. Without passing additional information on client side you can't react on it.

Comment: @dahrens Oh wait, I think I misunderstood. Yes, I have access to the client code. Im guessing you mean the template for the view right? If you mean the webpage requesting my view using the iFrame, then no, I don't.

Comment: You need to control the client code of the website that requests you through the iframe to be able to pass an HTTP header or GET parameter that indicates: I'd like the iframe represenation, pls.

Comment: You might do something in JS when your website was loaded in an iframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `{{ request.META.HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST }}` variable in the template. Example:

```
<section id="header" class="hero is-small is-info {% if request.META.HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST != 'document' %}is-hidden{% endif %}">
```

List of possible values for HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest