# Suppress Google Pageview Event in an AMP-IFRAME

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I have been recently asked to disable the additional Pageview event on Page nestet within an AMP-IFRAME.
The problem is, that both pages use the Google Analytics functions which is required so far, but sending 2 Pageviews at once does not seem to be right approach, even if there are actually two diffrent Pages with diffrent domains.

So the question is:

is there an possiblity to disable the pageview event to be fired when loading 
the amp-iframe content?

PS. All other events should be fired as well...

Comment: So to do this, I would think you'd need logic on the page to trigger the GA pageview events ONLY if it isn't being loaded in an iframe. So your next thing to find out is if you can detect using JS if a page is loaded through an iframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: thank you @XTOTHEL,i will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a flag to the embedded page via a query parameter.

```
<amp-iframe src="https://example.com/amp.html?embedded=true" ...> ...</amp-iframe>
```

You can then change the amp-analytics code in your backend to not render the page view trigger in the page.

Another option is to dynamically load the amp-analytics configuration and pass the embedded flag via [variable substitution](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#query-parameter).

```
<amp-analytics config="https://example.com/analytics.account.config.json?${queryParam(embedded)}">
```

`https://example.com/analytics.account.config.json` should then return different configurations based on whether `embedded` is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, this seems to be the best approach to realize this.