# inIframe function explanation

Tags: jquery

Right so I am a beginner to web development and I came across this piece of code:

```
$('#tweet-quote').on('click', function() {
 if(!inIframe()) {
  openURL('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + currentQuote + '" ' + currentAuthor));
 }
});
```

I understand everything except this

```
inIframe()
```

what is this function? I cant find anything on this particular function.

Comment: It's not a native JavaScript or jQuery function. Probably from some third part library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: it should be a defined function in a code! it's not a built-in function

Comment: Oh shite you are right. Pardon me