# Is there a way for a certain button to appear on a site if accessing through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, e-commerce

Simply but wondering if it is possible, with website owners permission to do following.

I want to add my own button to clients website(with permission).
I am aware I can add the button but wondering if it is possible that the button I add is only accessible and viewable if viewed through an iframe on my site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Comment: "Accessible" is quite broad term, just hiding an element doesn't prevent accessing it. An only truly inaccessible element is the one which never was loaded to a page, and servers are not aware where the requested page will be shown. So, I think what you need is not possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.