# Redirect if element is shown in embedded form

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help redirecting the page which has embedded form and if the element is shown, I want it to redirect to a certain page. Thank you!

```
<script>
if ( receipt number (element) is shown it will redirect below ) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question, currently it hardly makes any sense.

Comment: IF you need to check whether the script is executing inside an IFRAME - you can test for `window !== window.parent`, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/326076/5962802