# How to track traffic coming from an iframe with google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-tag-manager

My website will be used as an iframe on another website. My intention is to create a variable on google tag manager that will detect if the traffic I'm receiving is coming from a normal source or from a website with my iframe on it. I came up with this, but I don't think it could be correct.

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new "User defined variable" of type "Custom Javascript" with the Code that you have posted.

[image]