# Check if page is in a iframe in Chrome Incognito mode (window.top === window.self return true)

Tags: javascript, html

This snippet check if the current page is in a iframe.
The code works well in normal navigation mode but not in incognito mode on Chrome when domains of parent page and iframe are different (ex: localhost and localhost1).
In incognito mode always show 'NORMAL' alert message.

```js
if( window.top === window.self){
    alert('NORMAL') 
} else { 
    alert('IFRAME')
}
```

How can I make it work in incognito mode?

Comment: It works fine for me in incognito.

Comment: This related post has some other options available: [how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) specifically the answer by **Konstantin Smolyanin**

Comment: I've update the question specifying that domains should be cross origin